# What does the avformat_open_input() do?

Tags: c, ffmpeg

I am following [this](https://github.com/mpenkov/ffmpeg-tutorial/blob/master/tutorial01.c) code to work with FFmpeg library in C. FFmpeg library has very little documentation and it is difficult to understand what each function exactly does.

I understand the code (what is being done). But I am lacking clarity. Can anyone help me out please?

Q1) A **struct AVFrameContext **** and **filename** (the minimum non-NULL parameters required) are passed to the function avformat_open_input(). As the name suggests, the input file is 'opened'. How ?

Comment: `ffmpeg` comes with source, did you look/step inside?

Comment: You mean seeing the code of the library function ? Thanks for the suggestion :) I will see it immediately :)

Comment: @RomanR. it's absolutely ridiculous to ask users to read the damn source code of FFmpeg, it's a massive codebase, the function names and code style is hard to follow AT BEST, and I say that as someone that extended an internal decoder for them...

Comment: @MarcusJ: I see nothing ridiculous in locating `avformat_open_input` (a few seconds spent on search in given directory) and looking quickly at argument validation and what is in general taking place here. Eventually this is what other devs do without whining. Then the question here is "what does it do": so you open it and you see what it does.

Comment: The problem is there's 3 or 4 function calls within avformat_open_input, and ever more in those functions, it quickly becomes insanity.

Comment: One of the two major reasons FFmpeg/LibAV is a pain in the ass to use, is because it's spaghetti code, everything depends on everything else and it becomes circular without digging in with a metaphorical bulldozer to figure out what does what.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The main things that gets done in file_open are

- Allocate memory for AVFormatContext.
- Read the probe_size about of data from the file (input url)
- Tries to guess the input file format, codec parameter for the input file. This is done by calling read_probe function pointer for each of the demuxer
- Allocate the codec context, demuxed context, I/O context.

Comment: I read in [this](http://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/group__lavf__decoding.html) link that - "The function allocates an AVFormatContext, opens the specified file (autodetecting the format) and reads the header, exporting the information stored there into the pointer that we passed". What is header in a file ? Is it the first few bytes of the file ? Is the size of header fixed ? Is the information about probe_size in the header ?

Comment: Thanks for your answer . Can you elaborate it a little ? :)

Comment: header is the muxed file header e.g flv header, mp4 header, avi header. The information in header is specific to file format. The probe size is a command line parameter of ffmpeg "-probesize". This is the amount of data used by ffmpeg to autodetect the file format and other information (codec,width,height ....)

Comment: probe_size means the amount of data that the function decides to 'read' from the opened file inorder to detect some important stuff , right ? Is it fixed ?

Comment: your interpretation is correct.it has a default value, you can pass "-probesize" commandline parameter to change it.

Comment: Thanks for the help .. :) The information you provided sure cleared few doubts :)

Answer (score 4):

You can look it up in FFmpeg's `libavformat\utils.c` what is really taking place there:

```
int avformat_open_input(AVFormatContext **ps, const char *filename, AVInputFormat *fmt, AVDictionary **options)
{
    AVFormatContext *s = *ps;
    int ret = 0;
    AVDictionary *tmp = NULL;
    ID3v2ExtraMeta *id3v2_extra_meta = NULL;

    if (!s && !(s = avformat_alloc_context()))
        return AVERROR(ENOMEM);
        // on and on
```